# VSCode Maven project add a folder to source path

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, classpath

I am trying to run a file but I am getting these errors. After clicking on "add to source path" seen in the screenshot below, I get the following error.
[image: error 1]

This error below.
[image: error 2]

This is what my pom.xml file looks like. I added in configurations as seen below but it did not help.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>pizza.shop</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>1</version>

<configuration>
    <additionalClasspathElements>
      <additionalClasspathElement>Pizza/demo/src/main</additionalClasspathElement>
      <additionalClasspathElement>Pizza/demo/src/main/Insert</additionalClasspathElement>
      <additionalClasspathElement>Pizza/demo/src/main/Select</additionalClasspathElement>
      <additionalClasspathElement>Pizza/demo/src/main/Create</additionalClasspathElement>
    </additionalClasspathElements>
  </configuration>

<packaging>adapter</packaging>
<name>demo</name>

<properties>
    <!-- Use UTF-8 as the encoding of the adapter -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <!-- MobileFirst adapter deployment properties -->
    <mfpfUrl>http://localhost:9080/mfpadmin</mfpfUrl>
    <mfpfUser>admin</mfpfUser>
    <mfpfPassword>admin</mfpfPassword>
    <mfpfRuntime>mfp</mfpfRuntime>
</properties>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mfp</groupId>
        <artifactId>adapter-maven-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>8.0.2020110500</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mfp</groupId>
        <artifactId>mfp-security-checks-base</artifactId>
        <version>[8.0.0,9.0.0)</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.26</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mfp</groupId>
            <artifactId>adapter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What am I missing/doing wrong because `additionalClasspathElement` does not help or change anything.

Comment: All source elements should be in the directory src/main/java